# Mongodb find multiple and retrive one record for matching id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find many records in the same query, the records are of this type

```
{
    "key": 2,
    time: 3
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    time: 5
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    time: 4
  }
```

I'd like to retrive for example the records with `key inside [2,3]` and with the relative maximum amount of time, so in this case recrods with `{ "key": 2, time: 5 }` and `{ "key": 3, time: 4 }` should be returned.

So far i got only how to retrive the records with `key` inside in a proveded array but i'm not understanding how to get for each key in the array the record with the latest time, i'd like to not use the `where` operator.

Here is a playground with the provided scenario https://mongoplayground.net/p/5sWnn8_HnqK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregate function  to find max element for each key.
Example:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/P9JSuvTHdZa

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      key: {
        $in: [
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      time: {
        $max: "$time"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Edited: as in comment suggested

Comment: The answer would be better if you can post the complete query in the answer. Rather than just with link only.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is by matching the documents, sorting them descendingly and then choose the "first" document for each key, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      key: {
        $in: [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      time: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      first: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Yes, but you won't receive the other document fields in this case - and he implied he needs them, not just the maximum time value.